# eclipse android pass a java value to php by using HTTP

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, http

I want to pass the variable `q` from java to php.

```
String q = "select author from books where 1";
try{
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www2.XXXX./XXXX/X.php?qy="+q);
                //"http://10.0.2.2/tut.php", http://www.XXXX/XXXX/tut.php
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace(); 
                System.out.println("Exception 1 caught");
            }
```

However, the php file cannot get the value from java(php connected to mysql correctly).

php coding:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("XXX.XXX","XX","XXX");
mysql_select_db("XX",$con);

$st = $_GET['qy'];
$r = mysql_query("$st");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
$out[]=$row;
}

print(json_encode($out));
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I found that if I just pass the table name to php, it works. But if the passing variable become longer, it went to caught one. How can I fix this? How about passing more than one variable to php (i.e. `mysql_query("select $_GET['col'] from $_GET['table'] where $_GET['condition']");`)?

Comment: Do you realize how insecure this is?

Comment: Why?sorry, i'm new to that. what's wrong with my code?

Comment: If your PHP script executes an SQL query it receives from GET parameters, an attacker could execute a query of their choice, e.g. `DELETE FROM books`

Comment: `http://example.com?qy=revoke all privileges from user()`. Enjoy having your server totally DESTROYED by this ludicrously insecure code.

Comment: i see.how about passing more than 1 variable to php.(i.e. mysql_query("select $_GET['col'] from $_GET['table'] where $_GET['condition']");)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Post instead of Get, it's more secure.

Something like this:

```
    String col = "author";
    String table = "books";    
    String condition = "1";

    try{
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("col", col));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("table", table));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("condition", condition)); 

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www2.XXXX./XXXX/X.php");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            System.out.println("Exception 1 caught");
        }
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
  if (isset($_POST['col']) && isset($_POST['table']) && isset($_POST['condition'])){
      $columnName= $_POST['col'];
      $tableName = $_POST['table'];
      $condition = $_POST['condition'];


    $dbh=mysql_connect ("localhost", "username", "password") or die('Cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db ("database_name");

    $sql=mysql_query("select '$columnName' from '$tableName' where '$condition'");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) $output[]=$row;
    print(json_encode($output));
    mysql_close();
  }
?>
```

it works(by mandi yeung)

Answer (score 0):

Never ever send any queries to backend. Your approach is equivalent to an EditText where user can execute desired query on your database. Keep your queries out of your requests at any cost. Query parts (as previous uaer suggested) count too. Query parts from request actually do the same thing.
Sending select query to backend may (and totally will) grant any attacker full access to your database. That means he may change or just delete the data. 
I could just tamper your web packet and send drop table statement instead.

```
drop table authors;
drop table books;
```

sBetterapproach would be sending json requests like this:

```
String query = "{
    requestedData: getAllBooks,
    sessionId: 637euegdifoidhrgeydydihvr
}";

new BasicNameValuePair("smth", query);
```

Then from your php side you read your input as a plain text $_POST["smth"].

You must then decode your json value into object or array and determine what query you must run.

```
if ($_GET["smth"]["requestedData"] === "getBooks") {
    // get books query executed here
}
```

Remember: this approach is still not perfect, but it's better than yours